# More static files outside web2py directory

Tags: web2py

I would like to know is it possible to move static files outside the web2py directory and still reference with `URL('static', 'images/some_pic.png')`, similar to Django STATIC_ROOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let web2py serve static files, I believe they must be in the application's "static" folder. However, in production, it is recommended that you configure the web server to serve static files directly (see [Nginx example](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/R-2.14.6/scripts/setup-web2py-nginx-uwsgi-ubuntu.sh#L58)). In that case, you can of course still use the `URL()` function to generate URLs for static files.

Another option is to create symlinks in the "static" folder pointing to the files.